# Добавление кнопки на страницу расширением Chrome

Tags: javascript, chrome-extension

Content Scripts(CS) расширения Chrome, как мне стало известно, исполняется в "отдельном мире" (js Content Scripts видит DOM, но не видит родной js страницы- js страницы соответственно не видит CS). В результате не удается обработать клики по кнопке добавленной расширением на страницу функциями которые находятся в Content Scripts.

В Content Scripts:

```
  let div = document.createElement('div');
  div.className = "alert";
  div.innerHTML = "<button onclick=\"сlick\">Click me</button>";
  document.body.append(div);



function сlick() {
alert('123');   //здесь будет отправка в Popup например апями Chrome
}`;
```

Хочу события клика, по кнопке, добавленной на страницу расширением, передать в Popup расширения - как это сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказывается работает в Content Scripts обработчик по идентификатору например с помощью Jquery вот так:

```
 $('.alert').click(function(){
 alert('123');
  });
```

Не работает только onclick.   А дальше передаем апями в Popup как описано вот здесь: [Message Passing](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging)